# Synchronizing Jtable rows

Tags: java, swingworker

Just need a general idea how to "synchronize" the updating of rows of a Jtable under SwingWorker.

I have many SwingWorker threads all doing some processing and updating to a single Jtable. Sometimes the display display gets "jumbled" and not what i want.

Say for example:

```
if ( some condition ) {
  dtm.addRow( ... );   <---- using DefaultTableModel
  dtm.fireTableDataChanged(); <<---- have tried this, but still its jumbled up
  dtm.repaint() ; <<--- have tried this also, to no avail.
}
```

Usually how would one do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I have many SwingWorker threads all doing some processing and updating to a single Jtable.

That sounds like a bad idea. Have the SwingWorker threads communicate with a single entity (e.g. an overseer worker thread, or something in the main thread) which takes care of managing the JTable itself. Then you can use locks or `synchronized` or whatever to manage concurrent access to state data, and the JTable doesn't have to worry about that.